# std::fstream::write && std::fstream::putc std::ios::binary

Tags: c++, fstream

I suspect I am not even creating and opening a file for binary I/O using `std::fstream`

```
BinarySearchFile::BinarySearchFile(std::string file_name){

    // concatenate extension to fileName
    file_name += ".dat";

    // form complete table data filename
    data_file_name = file_name;

    // create or reopen table data file for reading and writing
    binary_search_file.open(data_file_name, std::ios::binary);  // create file

    if(!binary_search_file.is_open()){

        binary_search_file.clear();
        binary_search_file.open(data_file_name, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        binary_search_file.close();
        binary_search_file.open(data_file_name), std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate;
    }

   try{
       if(binary_search_file.fail()){
            throw CustomException("Unspecified table data file error");
       }
   }
   catch (CustomException &custom_exception){  // Using custom exception class
       std::cout << custom_exception.what() << std::endl;
       return;
   }    

}
```

I believe this is true because I am writing data

```
void BinarySearchFile::writeT(std::string attribute){
    try{
        if(binary_search_file){
             binary_search_file.write(attribute.c_str(), attribute.length());
        }else if(binary_search_file.fail()){
             throw CustomException("Attempt to write attribute error");
        }

    }
    catch(CustomException &custom_exception){  // Using custom exception class
        std::cout << custom_exception.what() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

But the file is a standard text file with readable text data.  I want to write the characters of a string or characters themselves in binary format (2 byte char).  I am attempting to operate a `std::fstream` similar to a [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Question is:  Did I create the file correctly and why am I not seeing binary data written?

Comment: I believe you need to use `binary_search_file.open(data_file_name.c_str(), std::ios::binary)`. Note the `c_str()`.

Comment: @Thomas: (a) Visual Studio provides an overload to support the OP's code; (b) so does C++11; (c) if it didn't, that would cause a compilation error, and it seems clear that the OP is not experiencing a compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did create the file correctly. You have a misunderstanding that there are two kinds of files, binary and text. Instead there are two kinds of I/O operations, text like `operator<<` and binary like `write`.

The reason that you aren't seeing two byte chars is that `std::string` only has one byte chars. If you want two byte chars use `std::wstring`.

Comment: `write` expects a `const char *` and a `std::wstring` is a `const wchar_t *` so it appears an explicit conversion is in order but how?  If I am writing data in binary I should use `write` correct?

Comment: @Mushy Yes an explicit cast is necessary, use reinterpret_cast like this `binary_search_file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(attribute.c_str()), ...`. And yes if writing binary use write (or put, if writing one byte at a time).

Comment: Something is still not setting with me properly.  If I am writing data in binary format then why does it appear in human-readable text form?

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting. Strings are human readable even when in binary. Are you expecting to see hex values or something?

Comment: I discovered that `binary_search_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&attribute), attribute.length() * 2);` writes the data in binary format and when opening the file, data is not in human-readable form. Reference [this].(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) Also, becuase char is a byte in c++ whereas two bytes in Java, I multiply the length of the string by two.